# c# findall in list conditions in string

Tags: c#, linq, list, findall

I have a list:

```
List<My_object> people
```

When I search throw list using:

```
List<My_object> result = people.FindAll(a => a.getGender() == "female" && a.getRelationship() == "Single");
```

Everything works perfect, but now I want to set conditions in run:

```
string condi = "a => a.getGender() == \"female\"";
```

How can I insert this string into FindAll as condition?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need to be able to handle arbitrary critera given through string expressions? Or do you need to say "if the user specified gender, I need to add in the criteria to look at the gender and compare to what the user selected"?

Comment: As an aside, those look like they should be `Gender` and `Relationship` properties... this isn't Java :)

Comment: Yes Lasse, this is right:"if the user specified gender, I need to add in the criteria to look at the gender and compare to what the user selected""

Answer (score 1):

You can't using FindAll.  The best option you have for that is dynamic LINQ.  See [this example by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).   [This Codeplex site](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) may also be helpful...

Comment: I download it, but I don't know how to use it: var result = people.Where("condition").Select(); give me an error

Comment: What error?  Knowing what kind of error would be helpful.  But you may want to go ahead and create a new SO question with the code and the error...

Comment: I this it is safer to write some if and create some dump list and then join them to one big result list

Comment: It really depends on your requirements.  Yes, in some cases, that might work better.  More code = more maintenance though too.